# Is there a way to sort a file into a list, each list item containing all information between two key words

Tags: python

I am creating a script to perform a tracert on many different IP's from an excel sheet.

I output all the commands to a text file. From this text file I want to pull certain results based on conditions I make.

The way I thought to do this is adding each command output to a list and then sorting through the list for specific parameters but I do not know how to do this.

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row): # for each row, starting row 2 to last
brIP = sheet.cell(row = row, column = 2).value 
if(brIP is None): # if row value is empty in col B break the loop
    break
command = subprocess.Popen(tracert + ' ' + brIP, stdout = logFile) # + ' >> ' + logFile) this has the cmd logging the file
command.wait()
```

Here is an example tracert output:

```
Tracing route to xxxxxxxxxxx over a maximum of 8 hops

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  xxxxxxxxxxx 
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  xxxxxxxxxxx 
  3     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  xxxxxxxxxxx 
  4    11 ms     9 ms     9 ms  xxxxxxxxxxx 
  5    21 ms    22 ms    23 ms  xxxxxxxxxxx 

Trace complete.
```

Essentially what I want is to loop through each tracert (sort by "tracing route" to "complete.") in my log file and then detect certain IP's within this block. I want to keep the whole block once something is detected.

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
for row in range(305, sheet.max_row): 
    brIP = sheet.cell(row = row, column = 2).value 
    if(brIP is None): 
        continue
    command = subprocess.Popen(tracert + ' ' + brIP, stdout = , subprocess.PIPE) 
    list.append(command.stdout.read()) # adds each output to list
    command.wait()
```

And create a list = [] somewhere above to append to.

Essential this creates each command output into a list entity which will make it easier for me to sort through the list itself rather than an entire text file

Comment: Have you thought of importing your log file into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: No I have not, this is my first script and I have not looked into pandas yet. I will check that out, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if your log file is well organized and in a tabular form like in your example, then look into the `pd.from_csv` method to create your Dataframe instance, then into the `df.sort_values`.